# .htaccess should redirect to specified site, but redirects it to some nonsense-repeating-wtf-page. Why?

Tags: php, apache, localhost

*Hey guys, so today I am here again with a new problem, and with a problem comes a question (and hopefully answer haha)*

Right, so I have downloaded **PHP** and **Apache 2.4**. Both are running perfect, I have PHP installed locally (`C:\php)`, and so I do have Apache (`C:\Apache24`) running as a Windows Service. All the .php files work when run from localhost, display correctly and .htaccess worked until a **redirection** I finally decided to do.

*And that's when the strange thing happened*

I put this code in my .htaccess in root directory:

> Redirect 301 / /FormTest/register/

(*Yes, I have configured to take index.php as index.html - default root directory document, and yes, the FormTest/register exist, and yes, I tried putting it as `/FormTest/register/index.html` too with the same result for those of you who would ask :)* )

So let's get to the thing: It would redirect me (in like 7 seconds (?)) to

> http://localhost/FormTest/registerFormTest/registerFormTest/registerFormTest/registerFormTest/registerFormTest/registerFormTest/registerFormTest/registerFormTest/registerFormTest/registerFormTest/registerFormTest/registerFormTest/registerFormTest/registerFormTest/registerFormTest/registerFormTest/registerFormTest/registerFormTest/registerFormTest/register

(Sorry for being long, that's what I really got)

***So, what the hell did it redirect me to, why, does it act like this - And of course hopefully how to solve it :D***

```
*I tried researching for answers, no found. I am thinking of => It's taking pretty long so it "requests" to redirect multiple times, when it actually tried to do all those (idk, 7 sec, 7 requests?) redirects, it joins them together and ends up like above*
```

Thanks in advance, any help appreciated!

Comment: I supect you created an infinity loop of redirects. Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/54746418/edit) your question to include the whole `.htaccess`, if possible.

Comment: Oh no. It actually redirects to the FormTest/register, but from there, it redirects again, and again, and again! So you're technically right, but this is my whole .htaccess!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your `Redirect` rule:

```
Redirect 301 / /FormTest/register/
```

Is not matching the URL `/`, it is matching any `/` character at the beginning of the URL. In particular, the above rule is meant to redirect `/foo/` to `/FormTest/register/foo`.

You want to tell Apache to only redirect the URL `/` and nothing else, use [RedirectMatch](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_alias.html#redirectmatch), which allows you to match a `/` as the only character in the URL (`$` is a regular expression symbol meaning "end of string" and `^` means the opposite, "start of string"):

```
RedirectMatch 301 "^/$" "/FormTest/register/"
```

Keep in mind though that this will not redirect `/index.html` or `/index.php` to the form test URL. You can add additional redirect rules to fix this:

```
RedirectMatch 301 "^/$" "/FormTest/register/"
RedirectMatch 301 "^/index\.html$" "/FormTest/register/"
RedirectMatch 301 "^/index\.php$" "/FormTest/register/"
```

(The quotes are optional.)

Comment: although i've not that much experience with apache / .htaccess configs, shouldn't the regex be `^/$` instead of `/$`, so it matches only the `/` and nothing else?

Comment: Hehe, you were **so close**! I know where you're heading, but you'd have to do "^/$" so it **starts** and **ends** with an "/", because technically any website can end with "/"!

(I'd appreciate if you fixed your answer if possible @AurelBílý. Thanks.

Thank you anyways!